# filter shiny DT using regex containing not string

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a quick question, regarding package `DT` implemented in `shiny`. I want to use the top filters in a renderdatable in a shiny app to filter out the rows that contain a specific word. I have set up in `options` `regexp=TRUE`, but I am still not able to make it work

I am using this regexp

```
^((?!intronic).)*$
```

I have tried escaping this part `((?!intronic).)` but it doesn't work either

**EDIT**

This is my complete code for rendering the table

```
      DT::datatable(df, 
    rownames = FALSE,
    selection = "none",
            style = 'bootstrap', 
            class = 'compact display',
            #class = 'compact cell-border stripe hover', 
            filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE), 
            escape = FALSE,
            extensions = c('Buttons'),
             options = list(
              stateSave = FALSE,
              ordering = FALSE,
              autoWidth = TRUE,
              searchCols = default_search_columns,
              search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE),
              columnDefs = list(
                list(
                className = 'dt-center',
                targets = cols_to_all,
                render = JS("function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                            "return type === 'display' && typeof data === 'string' && data.length > 14 ?",
                            "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 14) + '...</span>' : data;",
                            "}") 
                ),
                list(
                  visible = FALSE,
                targets = cols_to_hide                   
                )),
              initComplete = JS(
                  "function(settings, json) {",
                  "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'font-size': '12px'});",
                  "}"),
              #dom = 'Bfrtip',
              sDom = '<"top">Blrt<"bottom">ip', # remove search general box and keep the top filters
              #dom  = 'BT<"clear">frti',
              #dom = 'Bftir',
              scroller = TRUE,
              scrollX = TRUE,
              #scrollY = "800px",
              deferRender=TRUE,
              buttons = list('colvis'),                  
              #FixedHeader = TRUE,
              pageLength = 25,
              lengthMenu = list(c(25, 50, 100, -1), list('25', '50', '100', 'All'))#,
            )
```

I have included the `search` option in the list

**EDIT2**

This is an example of my daframe, the real one has more than 50,000 rows and 160 columns. However, I am interested in applying the filter to the column named `Func.refGene`

```
 >dput(df)
 structure(list(Chr = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
 "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
 "chr1", "chr1"), Start = c(69511L, 876499L, 877831L, 878314L, 
 879676L, 879676L, 879687L, 879687L, 881627L, 887560L, 887801L,  
 888639L, 888659L, 889158L, 889159L), End = c(69511L, 876499L, 
 877831L, 878314L, 879676L, 879676L, 879687L, 879687L, 881627L, 
 887560L, 887801L, 888639L, 888659L, 889158L, 889159L), GATK.RefCount   = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0"), GATK.AltCount = c("55", "60", "138", "184", "111", "111", 
"110", "110", "103", "66", "138", "73", "50", "96", "96"), GATK.Filter = c("MQ_LT_40", 
"PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", 
"PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS"), Func.refGene =   c("exonic", 
"intronic", "exonic", "exonic", "UTR3", "UTR3", "UTR3", "UTR3", 
 "exonic", "intronic", "exonic", "exonic", "exonic",   "splicing;intronic", 
 "splicing;intronic"), Gene.refGene = c("OR4F5", "SAMD11", "SAMD11", 
 "SAMD11", "NOC2L", "SAMD11", "NOC2L", "SAMD11", "NOC2L", "NOC2L", 
 "NOC2L", "NOC2L", "NOC2L", "NOC2L", "NOC2L"), GeneDetail.refGene = c(".", 
 ".", ".", ".", "NM_015658:c.*398C>T;NM_152486:c.*143G>A",    "NM_015658:c.*398C>T;NM_152486:c.*143G>A", 
"NM_015658:c.*387A>G;NM_152486:c.*154T>C",     "NM_015658:c.*387A>G;NM_152486:c.*154T>C", 
 ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "NM_015658:exon8:c.888+4C>G",     "NM_015658:exon8:c.888+3T>G"
 )), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There isn't enough code or example data here to see if there are any errors in your code or if there is something else going on. So the best we can do is make guesses with very little evidence. You'll get a lot better response if you make a question that includes example input data, the code you have tried, and the expected output.

Comment: could you run ````str(df) ```` so as to see what your df has in?

Comment: or optimally `dput(df)`,..

Comment: @BigDataScientist, I have added the `dput(df)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `regex` option like this:

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris, 
          options = list(search = list(regex = TRUE)))
```

Then you can check that `^((?!(setosa)).)*$` works well.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane but I have included the search in the options and still doesn't work in my datatable (see EDIT of my post)

Comment: @user2380782 Your code is not reproducible. I can't help.

Comment: I have run your code with a subset of my data, and, indeed the filter works, however when I run my whole app it doesn't work. Is there any possibility I can send you my code offline, my code is a bit long to be included here.

Comment: The package DT has to be at >= v0.11. cf [github.com/rstudio/DT #423 Nov 19': search highlight not working with regex input](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/423) .

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in mouse genes to remove "Rik" predicted genes. Here was my solution.

```
rik = grep("Rik$", rownames(DF))

datatable(DF[-rik,]) %>%
  ... %>%
  formatSignif(columns = c('log2.FC', 'adj.P.val'), digits = 3)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Sam Old but I want to do the filtering using top filter in the shiny app, not before in the data.frame